# An almost everywhere equation which implies that two functions agree up to a constant of unit modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb C$ are two (Lebesgue)-measurable functions such that for every $s \in \mathbb R$ it holds that
$$
f(t+s)\overline{f(t)}=g(t+s)\overline{g(t)}, \ \ \text{for almost every} \ t \in \mathbb R.
$$
Hence, the previous equality holds *almost everywhere* for *every fixed* $s$. I want to conclude that $f=cg$ a.e. for some complex number $c$ with $|c|=1$. If the equation above would holds everywhere in $t$ then this can be proven easily. I'm struggeling right now to find a formal and rigorous proof for "almost everywhere" case.

Answer (score 1):

A standard argument using Fubini's Thereom shows that for almost all $t$ we have $f(t+s)\overline {f(t)} =g(t+s) \overline {g(t)}$ for almost all $s$.  Fix one $t$ for which this holds and $f(t) \neq 0$. [You can do that as long $f$ is not almost everywhere $0$]. We now have $f(t+s)=cg(t+s)$ for almost all $s$ where $c=\frac   {\overline {g(t)}} {\overline {f(t)}}$. Hence, $f=cg$ almost everywhere.

[The Fubini argument looks at $\iint \chi_E$ where $E=\{((t,s): f(t+s)\overline {f(t)} \neq g(t+s) \overline {g(t)}\}$ and evaluates this double integral as iterated integrals].